# JSON.parse on a number as a string doesn't throw error

Tags: javascript, json

I believed that this is one of the ways to correctly distinguish an invalid ***JSON object as string*** from a valid one

```js
function isValidJson(s) {
  try {
    JSON.parse(s);
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(isValidJson(1234)); // true
console.log(isValidJson('1234')); // true
console.log(isValidJson('Is life a valid JSON?')); // false :(
console.log(isValidJson('{"a" : { "b": [1, 2, 3] }}')); // true
```

This is the most common answer I see, in regards to achieving the distinction. I don't seem to quite understand what is happening here. This snippet actually recognizes numbers and numbers as strings as valid JSON objects. Could anyone throw light on why/how this is happening?

Also, on reading the [MDN docs for JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), I found the reviver method. I wrote a function which seems to work for all scenarios. Would this function actually be the right way?

```js
function isValidJson(s) {
  try {
    JSON.parse(s, function(k, v) {
      if (k === "" && typeof v === "number") {
        throw "Invalid JSON";
      }
      return v;
    });
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(isValidJson(1234)); // false
console.log(isValidJson('1234')); // false
console.log(isValidJson('Is life a valid JSON?')); // false :(
console.log(isValidJson('{"a" : { "b": [1, 2, 3] }}')); // true
```

[EDIT] I may have wrongly implied that I'm looking to distinguish valid JSON strings. I meant, valid ***JSON objects as strings***. Edited the question with regards to this.

Comment: Do you consider arrays to be objects? Javascript does, but JSON doesn't. And what about null?

Comment: Yes. I need '[]' as well as '{}' to be considered as valid. null should not be considered valid, and I guess my solution doesn't consider null. I can change that. I'm more inclined towards understanding how JSON.parse doesn't throw an exception when I pass a number or a number string into it.

Comment: Your first function doesn't throw an exception because a number string is fine JSON, your second function does in fact throw that "Invalid JSON" exception in your if, since that one returns false for '1234'. So I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A JSON text can be any of the JSON data types.

```
1234
```

… is a valid JSON text consisting of a Number. (Passing `1234` as a number to `JSON.parse` works because it gets converted to a string by JavaScript's normal typecasting rules).

```
"Is life a valid JSON?"
```

… is a valid JSON text consisting of a String.

```
Is life a valid JSON?
```

… is not a valid JSON text. It is just a bunch of characters which don't match the syntax of any JSON data type.

So no. Your second function would not be right. It claims that `1234` is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I think the case where `isValidJsonString(1234)` returns `true` is just Javascript being its usual eager self at turning things into strings at the first opportunity. If you add a check to the function that the argument is actually a string, everything is fine:

```
function isValidJsonString(s) {
  if (typeof s !== 'string') {
    return false;
  }
  try {
    JSON.parse(s);
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

The others already work as they should.

> This snippet actually recognizes numbers and numbers as strings as valid JSON strings. Could anyone throw light on why/how this is happening?

It is happening because numbers as strings are valid JSON strings.

> [EDIT] I may have wrongly implied that I'm looking to distinguish valid JSON strings. I meant, valid JSON objects as strings. Edited the question with regards to this.

Your current method also doesn't do that, it only excludes numbers.

JSON values can be seven different things: object (in `{}`), array (in `[]`), string (in `""`), number, `null`, `false` or `true`. Of these, you exclude only the number.

If you use `typeof v !== "object"`, then accept only objects, arrays and `null`. Maybe that is what you want, maybe not.

If you only want JSON objects, just check that the first non-whitespace character in your JSON string is a `{`.